# Inserting data using value bound with WITH

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to `INSERT` some rows using the auto increment value obtained from another `INSERT`.

```
WITH id AS (
    INSERT INTO myTable
        (mt_name, mt_description)
        VALUES ('Name', 'Description')
        RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO anotherTable
    (at_id, at_foo, at_bar)
    VALUES (id, 'PLT', 50682),
           (id, 'PLT', 54482),
           (id, 'PLT', 52570),
           (id, 'PLT', 9192);
```

What I'm expecting is to `INSERT` a bunch of rows with the `at_id` column having the value that was returned by the first `INSERT`. But when I run this, I get:

```
psql:file.txt:100: ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 9:  VALUES (id, 'PLT', 50682),
```

Is it possible to insert a returned value this way? If so, what changes must I make to get this to work?

I'm using Postgres 9.3.5. The client and server have the same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
WITH id AS (
    INSERT INTO myTable
        (mt_name, mt_description)
        VALUES ('Name', 'Description')
        RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO anotherTable(at_id, at_foo, at_bar)
SELECT id.id, 'PLT', val.v
  FROM (VALUES (50682),(54482),(52570),(9192)) val(v)
 CROSS JOIN id;
```

Answer (score 1):

change your query like this

```
WITH id AS (
    INSERT INTO myTable
        (mt_name, mt_description)
        VALUES ('Name', 'Description')
        RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO anotherTable
    select id,'PLT', 50682 from id;
```

Comment: That doesn't really scale to inserting multiple values, though, which is crucial here.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following table definitions:

```
create table myTable
(
  id serial,
  mt_name text,
  mt_description text
);

create table anotherTable
(
  at_id serial,
  at_foo text,
  at_bar text
);
```

You could insert all of the items you listed in one `INSERT` statement by `UNNEST`ing an `ARRAY`, i.e.:

```
WITH id_res AS (
    INSERT INTO myTable
        (mt_name, mt_description)
        VALUES ('Name', 'Description')
        RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO anotherTable
    select id, 'PLT', unnest(ARRAY[50682, 54482, 52570, 9192]) FROM id_res;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5464a/1/0)

Note I changed the *CTE* to `RETURNING *` so the whole row would be accessible, but that can be changed back to just `id` if you will never have any use for any other column).

Also, I renamed the *CTE* something other than `id` so the code is clearer which is the column and which is the temp table by name and not solely by syntactic location. Otherwise, the query is of the form `SELECT id from id`.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

Complex queries can get sort of messy, depending on the circumstances, but there are many ways to help mitigate that...

For different values of the second column, you can always use a totally separate query, i.e. `(SELECT name from names where id = 10)` or something along those lines.

If it's more complicated still, you could drop the use of the *CTE* and instead use a *temp table*, so it's usable across the entire session and not just that one query (a *CTE* is essentially a temp table scoped to a single query). Then you could split a complex query into multiple temp tables and then do the final `INSERT`, or something along those lines, all while still having access to the first `INSERT`'s `id` value.

If the `mt_description` list was very large, you could reduce the complexity by dynamically generating the *SQL* in, say, *Python* or similar, so you don't need to manually type out the entire `ARRAY` contents.

Particularly if generating the SQL dynamically, I don't see why the above style would be overly messy, even with lots of data. *Postgres* is perfectly happy to handle seemingly (to the human eye) enormous queries. For example, I've dynamically generated queries that have thousands of items in an `IN` list within the `WHERE` clause, and, since it was dynamically generated, it wasn't particularly messy, and *Postgres* performed well in those cases.

Comment: That becomes pretty messy if the actual data being inserted is complex (multiple fields and the `'PLT'` not always being `'PLT'`).